# Undefined getIntent() method in SherlockFragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

Having a issue with the following error

`The method getIntent() is undefined for the type`

While using the following `extends SherlockFragment {`

Code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup grp, Bundle icicle) {

    View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, grp, false);
    web = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String url;
    url = extras.getString("url");
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return v;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using getActivity() ===> getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

```
   Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in your OnActivityCreated

> > Bundle bundle = UrFragment.this.getArguments();